# Function to draw a rectangle with C++

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I try to write a function that generates a rectangle which takes as input the following information:

*topLeftPoint*, and *(width and height)* of the desired rectangle. As the result it should return the coresponding vertices. I'm using the `OpenGL` coordinate system.

*topLeftPoint* can be a simple struct of two `ints` or `Vec2`.

Here is an example of how I try to solve this task:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auQ0P.png)

```
 float verticesOfRectangle[] =   
{  
   in.x(), in.y(),  
   in.x(), in.y() - h,  
   in.x() + w, in.y()-h,  
   in.x() + w, in.y(),  
}
```

What is wrong with my code? My final shapes doesn't look like a rectangle. It looks more likes this: [final shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBYDQ.png)

Comment: Are you using glRect() to draw??

Comment: It's not clear how you are drawing those vertices, but most likely you just need different permutation of them. Just keep reordering them until you find the right way.

Comment: Thank you for User_Targaryen, I just tried to build my own function which have to look like this, any way big thank you for offering quick shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing, reorder them like this:

```
float verticesOfRectangle[] =   
{  
   in.x(), in.y() - h,  
   in.x() + w, in.y() - h,  
   in.x(), in.y(),  
   in.x() + w, in.y(),  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help you:

```
void glRecti(GLint x1, GLint y1, GLint x1+w, GLint y1-h);
```

> The vertices are the two diagonal endpoints of the rectangle. `(x1,y1)` is the left topmost point while `(x1+w, y1-h)` is the right bottom most point, with `w` as the width and `h` as the height of the rectangle